# Git issue. Master branch staging files from .gitignore

Tags: git, merge, commit, gitignore

So, I have a git repository version controlling a Laravel project. It has a master and a development branch currently. I did an initial commit to the master branch then started working in the development branch.

I use Sourcetree for my commits etc.

I realised I haven't got my most recent changes in my master branch however when I go to my master branch I see that it's trying to stage vendor and storage files etc.

How can I go about fixing this problem? I am quite a few commits behind the development branch.

Comment: Did you ignore the files after they had been checked in previously? If so, that's the problem. Only untracked files can be ignored. Anything previously added to the repository will remain tracked, even if they match an entry in gitignore.

Comment: I was just about to post the answer here. It turns out i had added storage to the development branches gitignore since i had commited to master so i just had to swap out the branches, update gitignore and was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vendor/` directory into `.gitignore`.

Once you added the directory into `.gitignore`. Clear the git cache by running `git rm -r --cached .`

Note : If you want to unignore some files of `vendor/` directory then add this line to `.gitignore`

`!vendor/your_file.ext`